# How can I automate the creation of backups of emails using cronjobs?

Tags: php, email, backup, web-hosting, cron-task

I do not know how can I automate the creation of backups of emails  that are hosted in a hosting,I never automate anything, The programming language that hostings use is php,I do not know how can I do that.

I search documentation about that, but Im still confuse and I dont know how can I do that,I expected that the people of stack overflow help me with that and clarify my doubts to be able to automate the creation of email backups.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: use the [`imap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) functions to automate interaction with a mail server.

Comment: If you need just a backup of your emails, you do not need to use PHP. You can simply search for something like "backup IMAP," and you'll find numerous apps or email clients that can help you accomplish this task easily.